# Returning the results of four $resource calls as a JSON array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angular.js, asynchronous, ajax

Title pretty much says it. I need a way to elegantly handle multiple `$resource` calls in AngularJS. Right now, I just calling each other call on the `success` function and calling a callback function to spit the data out when it's down.

Here's what I have so far.

```
// DataService.js
var resource = $resource('/app/data/event/:id/:ext', {id:'@id',ext:'@ext'}, {"getAll": {method: "GET", isArray: false}});
getAllEvents: function (successcb) {
    var combinedJSON = "[";
    // First Call
    var firstFile = resource.get({ id: 1, ext: '.json' });
    firstFile.$promise.then(function (data) {
        combinedJSON += JSON.stringify(data) + ",";
        // Second Call
        var secondFile = resource.get({ id: 2, ext: '.json' });
        secondFile.$promise.then(function (data) {
            combinedJSON += JSON.stringify(data) + ",";
            // Third Call
            var thirdFile = resource.get({ id: 3, ext: '.json' });
            thirdFile.$promise.then(function (data) {
                combinedJSON += JSON.stringify(data) + ",";
                // Fourth Call
                var fourthFile = resource.get({ id: 4, ext: '.json' });
                fourthFile.$promise.then(function (data) {
                    combinedJSON += JSON.stringify(data) + "]";
                    successcb(combinedJSON); // This is the success call back
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

My callback function just spits out the data

```
// Controller.js
eventData.getAllEvents(function successcb(events) {
    $scope.foo = events;
});
```

Is there a better way to handle these types of situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never, and I mean NEVER, manually construct JSON. That's just asking for trouble. Construct the object then use `JSON.stringify`. FYI, arrays are valid JSON so you can construct an array and pass it to `JSON.stringify`.

Next, it doesn't seem like your calls  depend on each other. You can just launch them all in parallel and use `Promise.all` (or Angular's equivalent API) listen to know when all of them have resolved. The resolved value is an array of values in the same order as the promises. That guarantees that the first call's result is the first item in the resolved value.

Lastly, since you're already using promises, just return a promise from your function. Using callbacks in the presence of a promise defeats the entire purpose of promises.

One more thing, just pointing out that you are returning JSON, *a string*, from `getAllEvents` and not an object. Not sure why you're doing that exactly, but if you aim to get the object for manipulation, you can skip that part.

```
const resource = $resource('/app/data/event/:id/:ext', {id:'@id',ext:'@ext'}, {"getAll": {method: "GET", isArray: false}})

getAllEvents(){
  const promise1 = resource.get({ id: 1, ext: '.json' }).$promise
  const promise2 = resource.get({ id: 2, ext: '.json' }).$promise
  const promise3 = resource.get({ id: 3, ext: '.json' }).$promise
  const promise4 = resource.get({ id: 4, ext: '.json' }).$promise

  return $q.all([ promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4 ])
}

// Usage
someService.getAllEvents().then(values => {
  // values[0] = your first file
  // values[1] = your second file
  // values[2] = your third file
  // values[3] = your fourth file
});
```

Comment: Well the goal that I was trying to do was to combine the JSON files together. Hence the calls within each other, as well as adding an `[` and `]` at the beginning/end of the file. Also I was adding a `,` in between each file. So essentially I wanted to return an array of the JSON values.

Comment: You should still be able to call `successcb()` and pass `values` to it...